# Is there any intuition behind implicit functions?

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

From my knowledge so far, pretty much all functions take an input and spit out some output. However, with implicit functions, this isn't necessarily the case, and that intuition breaks apart for me. For instance, in:

$$y + \ln y = \sin x$$

My intuition goes out the window. With input $x$, we get.. output $y$ summed with the natural logarithm of output $y$. Does anyone have any explanation on how to properly comprehend this?

Comment: The input is $x$. The output is the number $y$ that satisfies $y+\ln(y)=\sin(x)$.

Comment: $littleO that's a very specific set of numbers. Wouldn't that be a function for an output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the nature of an implicit function is to obscure this input-output relationship. In fact, generally if you write something of the form $g(x,y) = 0,$ it won't be a function at all, but a relation.

Nonetheless if the definition of a function is satisfied  (i.e. for every $x$ in some domain there is a *unique* $y$ satisfying $g(x,y) = 0$), your implicit function is sure-as-day a function and there should really be no inhibition to thinking of it as an input-output relationship. After all, every $x$ has a unique $y$ associated with it. So $x$ is the input and $y$ is its output.

Your example $y+\ln(y) = \sin(x)$ is in fact a true function. The way you can tell this easily is that the left-hand side is an increasing, and thus one-to-one, function of $y$ on its domain $(0,\infty).$

You can even use this fact to make the input-output relationship clearer. Let $h(y) = y+\ln(y).$ As I said before, this is an increasing, thus one-to-one, thus *invertible* function. So you can write your relation as $$ h(y) = \sin(x)$$ and then $$ y = h^{-1}(\sin(x))$$ where $h$ is the inverse that we know exists thanks to the increasingness of $h.$ Hey! We've written the function in an explicit form (even though we've had to use an unfamiliar function--the inverse of $y+\ln(y)$-- to do so).

But don't let the fact that this one has a nice way to write it in explicit form allow you forget the what I said at the end of the second paragraph. Regardless if you can get it into explicit form or not, if a relation happens a function, you can think of it as input-output... that goes hand in hand with the definition of function.

Comment: This was a fantastic answer so I appreciate that. Few questions: a) Can you elaborate why a function is a function if $g(x, y) = 0$? I can't think of a time I can't do that. Just subtract the terms from one side. b) Why does the increasingness of $h(y)$ imply it has an inverse, and would its inverse be in terms of $x&?

Comment: a) Not sure I exactly get what you're asking here, but I think maybe I've been confusing with the notation $g(x,y) = 0.$ This is just a way to express an arbitrary relation (not necessarily a function), *in terms of* a two variable function $g$. For instance yours can be expressed $g(x,y) = y+\ln(y)-\sin(x)=0.$ Also we can express the (non-function) relation of a circle as $g(x,y) = x^2+y^2-1 = 0.$  A relation is a function *by definition* if for every $x$ in the domain there is a unique $y$ such that $(x,y)$ satisfies the relation. Nothing to do with $g$; everything to do with input-output.

Comment: b) We can look at the graph of a relation on the $x-y$ plane. If it's a function, it passes the so-called 'vertical line test' that no vertical line intersects it at more than one point (input-output). The inverse of the relation just flips $x$ and $y$ so flips the graph on its side. If the inverse is a function, it will pass the vertical line test, which means the original function must pass a "horizontal line test" where every $y$ has a unique $x$ (1-to-1). An increasing function is 1-to-1 since it can't "double back on itself" and fail the horizontal line test, it needs to keep increasing.

Comment: Your example highlights my question well. I can't see when a function *can't* be expressed that way.  When *can't* I just subtract a term from the RHS like subtracting $sin\ x$ to have $y + ln(y) - sin(x) = 0$? In addition, I don't see how $x^2+y^2-1=0$ isn't a function and $y + ln(y) - sin(x)$ is. That is, just by looking at the equations themselves. I understand you defined it afterward, but are you saying for the circle equation a value of $x$ has a set of outputs rather than one? Because the vertical line test is something I get.

Comment: Well consider $x=0$. There are two values of $y$ that satisfy $x^2+y^2=1$... $y=\pm1$. This means the circle relation is not a function. And you should see this corresponds to it failing the vertical line test at $x=0$. The reason that the same argument doesn't work is that, unlike $h(y)=\ln(y) +y$, $h_2(y)=y^2$ is not a one to one function. (It occurs to me now that perhaps part of the confusion is that I'm considering functions of $y$ along with viewing $y$ as a function of $x$.)